# Function that removes zeroes from list?

Tags: python-3.x

I just need a function that removes zeroes from an input list

```
def no_zero(a):
    pos=0
    while (pos+1)<=len(a):
        if a[pos] == "0":
            a.remove[pos]
        pos= pos +1
    return a

print(no_zero([0,1,0,2,0,3]))
```

I should be getting an output of 1,2,3 but instead it skips right to return a. Any pointers as to why? Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/):

```
def no_zero(a):
    return [x for x in a if x != 0]
print(no_zero([0,1,0,2,0,3]))
```

Additionally, the reason your code currently isn't working is because you are comparing the items to a string (`"0"`) instead of an integer (`0`). You are also attempting to modify a list as you iterate over it, which means that your indices don't correspond to the original indices of the list, and your result will be wrong.

Comment: Also passing pos to `remove()' which expects a value.

Comment: So what is that line saying. Change the string elements back to themselves only if not equal to 0?